# Unable to access ViewController which is present inside Pod

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods

I have created a `UIViewController`(TestViewController.swift) which I have created in a `Test.xcodeproj` and want to access this `TestViewController.swift` and its methods in another `abc.xcodeproj`.

Example -

```
import Test

class abcViewController: TestViewController {
}
```

I have added `abc.xcodeproj` and `Test.xcodeproj` in my project's Pod file.

But I am not able to inherit TestViewController in `abcViewController`. I want to create my project using LEGO pattern.

Please suggest what should be the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance that `TestViewController` is marked `internal` as this is the default value. This prevents it from being seen by other modules, which would be the case when using CocoaPods.

To correct this, TestViewController needs to either be marked as `public` or `open`.

The following [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) covers access levels in case you are not familiar with this and wish to understand the difference between public & open.

Comment: I was doing a mistake in adding open class. It worked using open. Thanks